# Comparison between N data

Tags: c

I want compare N data of float type. This comparison must be done with a tolerance.

That means if the difference between 2 data (within N data) is less than or equal the tolerance then this 2 data will be considered valid, and I get one data, otherwise if the difference is more than tolerance then the data is invalid.

Have you any idea?

here is my code:

```
 float mytab[N];
 int i,j,index=0;
 for (i = 0; i < N-1; i++)
 {
   for (j = i+1; j < N; j++)
    {
      if(tab[i].valid && tab[j].valid)
       {
          if ( ABS(tab[i]-tab[j])<= toleance)
            {
            mytab[index] = tab[i];
            index++;    
            } 
       }
    }
  }

//after i search the min value of mytab which constain a 
  valid value within tolerance.
```

Example:

```
tolerance = 0.15;
Data: 20.005, 20.017, 21.20, 21.25, 25.75, 25.9, 20.1
```

In this example, if we based on the tolerance, we can choose (20.005 OR 20.017 OR 20.1) OR (21.20 OR 21.25). 
But if we based on majority voting, we choose 20... instead of 21...

Comment: You I have Idea. But can you please provide your attempt. SO can help you if you atleast try something.

Comment: yes I tried but I failed to find a generic algorithm.

Comment: Please edit your post with that attempt.

Comment: Can you provide a small sample input and what you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 1):

Please, make yourself clearer. Depending on the set of numbers, you can create multiple (differents and not intersecting) subsets that share this property. 
If you intend to create the largest subset with values that are within a tolerance range to every single value of the original super set, than it's unique, but you're doing it the wrong way. You should, for each value in the set, if it's within tolerance range of every single value in the set. And only after checking with every single number, you can include it.

Like this:

```
float mytab[N];
int marker=1; //marker that will tell if any number is outside tolerance range of some other element (then marker will be converted to 0
 int i,j,index=0;
 for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
 {
   marker=1 //for every new number, reset marker
   for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
      if(tab[i].valid && tab[j].valid)
       {
          if ( fabs(tab[i]-tab[j])> toleance)
            {
            marker=0;
            } 
       }
    }
    if(marker)
      {
      mytab[index]=tab[i]; index++; //marker will only be 1 if the number is within tolerance range of every element
      }
  }
```

Of course it's a very inneficient code. The greatest ranges will be between your candidate number and the smallest and largest number in your set. So, what I would do is to sort your list (or simply discover which is the largest and the smallest number in your set), and compare each element to those 2 elements. If they are within range with those, they are with everyone else. So 2 comparisons for each number, and not n (or n/2 if you were a bit smarter than me in the code above, like you tried to be in first place)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your basic question, you need to compare two floats. I think you are close with ABS ... but you need the floating-point version `fabs` available in `math.h` in **C99**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
    float f1 = 1.00001;
    float f2 = 1.00003;
    float tol= 0.00010;

    if (fabs(f1 - f2) <= tol) {
        puts("Test1: f1 and f2 are equal-ish.");
    } else {
        puts("Test1: f1 and f2 are not equal-ish.");
    }

    tol= 0.0000001;
    if (fabs(f1 - f2) <= tol) {
        puts("Test2: f1 and f2 are equal-ish.");
    } else {
        puts("Test2: f1 and f2 are not equal-ish");
    }
}
```

Testing

```
$ cc -g -Wall -O0 -std=c99 -pedantic -o Test test.c && ./Test
Test1: f1 and f2 are equal-ish.
Test2: f1 and f2 are not equal-ish
```

Comment: My problem is not in ABS but it is to decide which value is correct between a lot of values. And i want check each two value using a fast algorithm.